# About finite posets without intervals of size 3

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, posets

Let $P$ be a finite poset (partially ordered set).

I am wondering whether the following condition on $P$ has been studied somewhere:

> (#) No interval $[a,b]$ in $P$ has $3$ elements.

Note that intervals with $3$ elements are necessarily isomorphic to a total order on $3$ elements.

For example, the condition (#) holds in the standard posets of set partitions and noncrossing partitions. It does not hold in the Tamari lattices.

Condition (#) implies that no interval in $P$ can be isomorphic to a total order of cardinality of least $3$. So  intervals of cardinality at least $3$ in these posets have an antichain of size at least $2$.

There is a classical notion of *thin poset*, where intervals of length 2 are isomorphic to a boolean lattice of cardinality $4$. This implies (#).

So my question is

> Is there an established name for the condition (#) ? Did it appear somewhere ?

This should not be confused with the avoidance of $3$-chains $a < b < c$, which is much more restrictive.

Comment: Relevant discussion: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330335/

Comment: Thanks. So this is known as 2-thick posets. And Eulerian posets are 2-thick.

Comment: See Theorem 7 of Logan and Shahriari, "A new matching property for posets and existence of disjoint chains."

Comment: Logan and Shahriari is here: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcta.2004.06.002

Comment: See Theorem 2 of Bjorner, "On complements in lattices of finite length," Discrete Mathematics 36 (1981), 325-326.

Comment: Thanks. Björner article is here : https://doi.org/10.1016/S0012-365X(81)80027-1